# The import com.google.android.gms.common.api cannot be resolved

Tags: oauth, google-plus, google-api-client

I have downlaoded the demo project from [androidhive.com](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/) Trying to integrate Google plus auth in my app. But cannot import googleapiclient . I have attached a screenshot here.

[image]

I have imported google-play-library-service from android sdk -extras  and selected copy the project into workspace while importing. After that i have added that library project to my google plus integration project. But all time i am gettng the error shown in the screenshot.